# Audio/Voice Chat over UPD with C#

Tags: c#, voip, rtsp

I'm pretty newbie on this field, i already wrote some TCP-IP client-server apps in C#, but those simply sent text based information to the server and back, not voice.

I have tried to make some research, but i only found external SDKs like twilio, and some examples 10-12 years ago.

Is it possible to send realtime audio chat from client to server using UDP protocol in C#? Where should i start, are there any example? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Voice chat is not easy. First you need to record audio from the microphone using the API specific to your OS (Windows/Linux) then send the audio over the network (probably with some buffering to increase stability) and then play the audio on the other side using API specific to your OS. External SDKs are probably the easiest for newbies, these SDKs will abstract all of the above.

Comment: Always check codeproject to see if there is available code.  I found following : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482735/TCP-Audio-Streamer-and-Player-VoIP  You can easily change TCP to UDP if necessary.

Comment: jdweng, this code example is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you! Add this link as an answer and i accept it.